# Find neighbors of a given position

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list of tuples like `[(4,6),(0,3),(7,9)]` and it is in a matrix with 8 rows and 10 columns. I want to find the neighbor locations for the tuples.

For example, I would expect:

```
Neighbors (4, 6): (3, 6) (4, 5) (4, 7) (5, 6)
Neighbors (0, 3): (0, 2) (0, 4) (1, 3)
Neighbors (7, 9): (6, 9) (7, 8)
```

The neighbor position must be in the matrix.

I've tried converting the list of tuples into list of lists，but I'm stuck on creating a loop to find these neighbors.

```
l = [(4,6),(0,3),(7,9)]
lst = []
rows = 8
columns = 10
for i in l:
    lst.append(list(i))
```

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: First of all, finding neighbors of a grid point is a well-covered technique.  See [How much research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Second, although you clearly know how to find the neighbors yourself, you've made no attempt to code how you do it.  We expect you to make that attempt before posting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting the tuples to lists is not at all necessary.

Write a function to return the neighbors of a single point (the function should loop over all the possible neighbors and then filter the results to those that are within the bounds of the matrix), and then use that function in another loop to get the neighbors of all the points.

```
>>> from typing import List, Tuple
>>> def neighbors(coords: Tuple[int, int], rows: int, cols: int) -> List[Tuple[int, int]]:
...     y, x = coords
...     return [
...         (y + dy, x + dx)
...         for dy, dx in [(0, 1), (1, 0), (-1, 0), (0, -1)]
...         if y + dy in range(rows) and x + dx in range(cols)
...     ]
...
>>> neighbors((7, 9), 8, 10)
[(6, 9), (7, 8)]
>>> [n for p in [(4, 6), (0, 3), (7, 9)] for n in neighbors(p, 8, 10)]
[(4, 7), (5, 6), (3, 6), (4, 5), (0, 4), (1, 3), (0, 2), (6, 9), (7, 8)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read tuples like lists so maybe try this?

```
l = [(4,6),(0,3),(7,9)]
lst = []
for i in range(len(l)):
    x = l[i][0]
    y = l[i][1]
    if x - 1 >= 0:
        lst.append((x - 1, y))
    if x + 1 <= 7:
        lst.append((x + 1, y))
    if y - 1 >= 0:
        lst.append((x, y - 1))
    if y + 1 <= 9:
        lst.append((x, y + 1))
```

You can then save those values wherever you want to after each iteration.
Hopefully this helps

Comment: I think you should loop over `range(len(l))` and not over `l`. Your code throws `TypeError`

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate the help